# how can I verify mobile number is register on whatsapp using c#?

Tags: c#, whatsapp

I want to verify, is mobile number register on whatsapp using c#? I try to search but I did not find any API from whatsapp.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **no** public API for WhatsApp.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [WhatsApp ToS](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/#terms-of-service):

> You **must not** [...], including that you must not directly or through automated means: [...] (f) **collect the information of or about our users** in any impermissible or unauthorized manner

I'm certain there are wrappers out there that allow you to do so, but you using those libraries are violating the ToS. Also, asking *which* library to use for this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.